# Refresh id_token on client side: Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, adal

I'm using ng2-adal npm lib to generate id_token and access_token. Since the id_token and access_token are valid for 30 mins and 60 mins respectively, I'm trying to come up with a way to refresh the id_token in every 20 minutes in the background. One way to do this might be:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.adalService.login();
});
```

Adal Service login method will regenerate the token and save it to browser local storage. But, with every token regeneration, it will also refresh the application. So, can I somehow avoid refreshing the app and just refreshing the token in the background with user's knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refresh the application, you can run the same code in a iframe just as the way of [adal.js library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js) renew the id_token.

```
AuthenticationContext.prototype._renewIdToken = function (callback) {
    // use iframe to try refresh token
    this.info('renewIdToken is called');
    var frameHandle = this._addAdalFrame('adalIdTokenFrame');
    var expectedState = this._guid() + '|' + this.config.clientId;
    this._idTokenNonce = this._guid();
    this._saveItem(this.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.NONCE_IDTOKEN, this._idTokenNonce);
    this.config.state = expectedState;
    // renew happens in iframe, so it keeps javascript context
    window.renewStates.push(expectedState);

    this.verbose('Renew Idtoken Expected state: ' + expectedState);
    var urlNavigate = this._getNavigateUrl('id_token', null) + '&prompt=none';
    urlNavigate = this._addHintParameters(urlNavigate);

    urlNavigate += '&nonce=' + encodeURIComponent(this._idTokenNonce);
    this.registerCallback(expectedState, this.config.clientId, callback);
    this.idTokenNonce = null;
    this.verbose('Navigate to:' + urlNavigate);
    frameHandle.src = 'about:blank';
    this._loadFrameTimeout(urlNavigate, 'adalIdTokenFrame', this.config.clientId);
};
```

However the `ng2-adal` the library doesn't provide the `_renewIdToken` method, if you also want this function, you may submit the feedback from the [its project site of GitHub](https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal).